# Spring Framework logs not printing with log4j

Tags: spring, log4j

I am building a web application using spring MVC. I want to print detailed springFramework logs for debugging purpose
here are my log4j.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=trace, stdout , FILE

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=E:/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.org.springframework=trace 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=trace
log4j.logger.controller.loginContoller=trace
```

However logs from spring framework are not printing and all other logs like hibernate framework, my custom logs are print properly.

I am using spring 4.0 and log4j 1.2 version.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you put the log4j.properties in the src folder ?

Comment: its in src/log4j folder

Comment: Please change log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\myapp.log

Comment: File is created and all logs other than springframework is printed in file.
springframework logs not printed either in file and console

Comment: Can you please share the spring code where you are using the logger?

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: I am using simple spring MVC

Comment: I need internal logs from spring framework, whatever logging code I have added its working fine and prints log
e.g. in controller class I added entering exiting logs that are printed
I face issue to get logs from spring framework jars